# CSRF token missing or incorrect (Django)

Tags: javascript, html, django, csrf

My form is created like so

```
<form class="k-form" id="k_form" novalidate="novalidate">{% csrf_token %}
```

and closed later in the html.

This is my AJAX post:

```
    $('#submit').on("click",function(e){
    var ready_to_submit = true;
    if(ready_to_submit){
        e.preventDefault();
        var local_data = new Object();
        local_data.csrfmiddlewaretoken = $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val();

        console.log(local_data.csrfmiddlewaretoken);
        var json_data = JSON.stringify(local_data);

        console.log(json_data);
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'/create_new_group/create_group/',
            data:json_data ,
            success:function(data){
                    if(data.status == 1){
                            //success!
                            console.log('Success!')
                    }
                    else if(data.status == 2){
                            //failed
                            console.log('Failed!')
                    }
            }
    });

    }
});
```

This returns Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.): /create_new_group/create_group/ on my Django server. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: when you inspect the request in your browser developer tools network tab, is it sending the correct data in the format expected by the server?

Comment: are you loggedin? if not csrf token wont be available. check in your cookies, if this token exists.

Comment: Try using `$("#k_form").serializeArray()` instead of `json_data` variable in the `data` option. It will serialize everything inside form, including csrf token.

Comment: It works fine when I just pass the data like so: {
     csrfmiddlewaretoken:$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),}   but I want to have the data be dynamic. So I don't know whats going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding to your imports:

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
```

and above your view function:

```
@method_decorator(csrf_exempt, name='dispatch')
```

It solved my Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.):